# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'launch'

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Running `python3 rrbot_system_position_only.launch.py` from here https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_control_demos/blob/master/ros2_control_demo_bringup/launch/rrbot_system_position_only.launch.py. But following the error message appears

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ros2_control_demos/ros2_control_demo_bringup/launch/rrbot_system_position_only.launch.py", line 15, in <module>
    from launch import LaunchDescription
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'launch'
```

I already tried the solution suggested in https://answers.ros.org/question/389046/importerror-no-module-named-launch/ but that did not work. Can you guys please help me solve this error? Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/411503/modulenotfounderror:-no-module-named-%27launch%27/) by [jlichong](https://answers.ros.org/users/134474/jlichong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2023-01-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Actually turns out I had to follow the setup instructions for ROS2 from the tutorials here: https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials.html

---

Originally posted by [jlichong](https://answers.ros.org/users/134474/jlichong/) with karma: 16 on 2023-01-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0